# one background image not showing while another is

Tags: css

I have two images in the same directory. When I try to use one as a background image using css it does not show but when I use the other it does. What in the world is going on here?

Just for reference here is my css code.

This one does not work

```
a:hover {
    background-image: url("images/menu-ident.png");
    background-size: 110px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: bottom center;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

This one does work

```
a:hover {
    background-image: url("images/logo.png");
    background-size: 110px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: bottom center;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Comment: Check the following: Are they in the same folder? Are there any typos on the name? Is the extension correct? if yes, try renaming the image or use single quotes.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your images folder

Comment: of course this doesn't work - the second one overwrites the first one (same elements selected). if want to use multiple background-images on the same element look here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: I am not repeating the code I was showing that all the code was the same except for the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

of course this doesn't work - the second one overwrites the first one (same elements selected). if you want to have multiple background-images on the same element look here: https://w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

```
a:hover {
  background-image: url("images/menu-ident.png"), url("images/logo.png");
  background-size: 110px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: bottom center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

if you need two differents backgrounds for two different elements you need different css selectors like classes or ids:

```
a.bg-1:hover {
  background-image: url("images/menu-ident.png");
  background-size: 110px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: bottom center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a.bg-2:hover {
  background-image: url("images/logo.png");
  background-size: 110px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: bottom center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

}